# Running Raspberry Pi .img file on an android device

Tags: raspbian, image, android

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and the lastest Raspbian is installed. I've run some java `.jar` file on it.
Now, I run an armhf Debian on my android device with [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy&hl=en).

Is it possible to run Raspbian `.img` backup file to run on a chroot environment on an android device?
Otherwise, how is it possible to run java `.jar` file on armhf a chroot environment? (Oracle preferred)

Comment: Why would you want to run Raspbian if you already have Debian armhf running?

Comment: I run a project on Raspbian and I need JRE package. Up to now, I can't install JRE on Debian armhf. It's my main reason.

Comment: If your main concern is getting the Java Run-time Environment installed on Linux within Android ya might have an easier time installing it from source. Few years back I wrote a [guide](http://forums.rptools.net/viewtopic.php?t=24082) on installing JDK and JRE on Android running a Linux chroot, however, I'd advise **not** using the script as it has been sometime and last time I went through the steps I had to make an account with Java in order to access the archive as the use case I had at the time required the browser plugin too. Let me know if ya get stuck and I may post a full answer.

Comment: @S0AndS0 I changed plan and run centos on linux deploy as chroot environment. I'm curious about your guidance. All in all, thank you.

Comment: The easiest thing to try would be installing the _`openjdk-<version>-jdk`_ and _`openjdk-<version>-jre`_ from your distribution's package manager, eg `zypper search openjdk` _should_ list'em if available on your device. If the application that requires JRE is _happy_ with the open versions then ya don't have to mess with source installing, and if not let me know so that I can move this up the _stack_ of planed project rewrites... it kinda needs a rewrite as it was written back for version Java versions 6/7 (when ARMel was still a thing) and things are up to 9 last I checked.

Answer (score 1):

It might be good to update the question and perhaps have it moved over to the Android *sub-stack*

> > I run a project on Raspbian and I need JRE package. Up to now, I can't install JRE on Debian armhf. It's my main reason

As this is still on the RPi related sub-domain, the following I dug up from my notes on trying to get WebEx hosing and viewing on Raspbian.

> Side note to readers, WebEx didn't really function but the basic steps are similar for other Browser + JRE apps so mileage may vary.

---

### Install depends and compatible web-browser

```
apt-get install firefox-esr libcanberra-gtk-module gtk2-engines-murrine libxtst6 libxmu6 icedtea-plugin
```

### Add non-sudo user without passphrase

```
useradd --shell /bin/bash --create-home --user-group moz
```

### Login to new user and run web-browser

```
su - moz
$(which firefox-esr)

## Or all in one line
# su - moz -c "$(which firefox-esr)"
```

### Download Java 7u4 for Embeded from the following link

```
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/ejre-7u4-download-1595957.html
```

> Note, version is only important if using JRE/JDK for applications dependent upon the browser plug-in (*`.so`* file), above was the last version I could find with it still included, otherwise it's probably best to download the latest instead.

### Un-Tar the dowloaded source

```
tar fvx ejre-7u4-fcs-b20-linux-arm-vfp-client_headful-12_apr_2012.tar.gz
```

### Make a directory for Mozilla plugins

```
mkdir -p ${HOME}/.mozilla/plugins
```

### Symbolicly link `libnpjp2.so` to the above directory

```
_plugin_source="${HOME}/Downloads/ejre1.7.0_04/lib/arm/libnpjp2.so"
_plugin_dest="${HOME}/.mozilla/plugins/libnpjp2.so"

ln -s "${_plugin_source}" "${_plugin_dest}"
```

### Restart Mozilla then navigate to the following URL

```
https://www.webex.com/test-meeting.html
```

Click through prompts to allow stuff to run till either pass or fail

---

Other applications may require other (or all) bits to be symbolically linked, but the procedure is pretty much the same... well once one tracks down where an application expects things to be.

While the above was a failure in that WebEx didn't want to run on Raspbian, other things do work on either Android running a Linux chroot or an ARMhf computing development board, eg. the MapTools *suite* was totally functional albeit much, much slower on a single core ARMel Android *over-clocked* to ***`800`***<sub>MHz</sub>, and JMonkey once setup on an ARMhf device wasn't any more sluggish than running anything else over an RDP session forwarded over SHH.

As I'm not certain what application the OP is running on RPi and wanting to run on Android with Linux chroot, I think I'll have to call this answer as complete as it'll get without more information. Good luck!

Comment: What is the Android sub-stack? What is the RPi related sub-domain? Where do you execute these commands? On the android device?

Comment: [Android _sub-stack_](https://android.stackexchange.com/)... You are here!... Yes on the Android device within a chroot Linux shell. Which is a _process_ to setup but I've found _use cases_ for such things... Generally over an SSH connection to the ARMel/hf device, but yes these are commands to run on the _target_... However, getting full JDK/JRE requires significantly more linking and updating of various executable paths such that other versions or OpenJDK/JRE do not conflict with the source installed version.

Comment: Thank you for the time that you have spent on answering this question. I preferred Oracle java, however, it's one of the solutions.

Comment: @M.Rostami You're very welcome! Recently I took another look at Oracle and found they've made things even more difficult to install, old guides suggesting a PPA are now broken because of licensing changes. So if your project doesn't require Oracle, as of 2020, it's going to be much easier to use OpenJRE/JDK. If you run into issues with a specific set of Java based software (that's freely available), feel free to tag (`@`) me within another question.

Comment: @S0AndS0 To be honest, that project has stopped because of the chroot environment limitations. Alright, I'll do it if the project continues.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the update... One option to workaround limitations is to use a _`shroot`_ setup instead of `chroot`; the [Debian Kit](https://sourceforge.net/p/debian-kit/code/ci/master/tree/) application by `sven-ola` can be modified to run on ARMhf CPUs by following a [Blog post](http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/running-debian-armhf-alongside-android) by `skyleecm`, which _should_ allow for accessing Android hardware from within the Linux environment. And setting up SSH can help with accessing the device from something with a full keyboard and larger screen too.